# LibDir missing in python install of mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

Trying to install mod_wsgi so I can get a django program I made hooked up with apache in Windows (guessing this is a lot easier in linux nowadays, but there's some windows-only commandline junk I need to do in my django program which is forcing me to use windows).

This is what I get when I try installing via pip:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod-wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.4.13.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-build-8o45w4\mod-wsgi\setup.py", line 304, in <module>
        'libpython%s.a' % PYTHON_VERSION)):
      File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
        result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
      File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
        if len(p) > 1:
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-build-8o45w4\mod-wsgi
```

I've tried a lot before asking here, including [installing from the source](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi) - which worked after hacking, but gave me a "module PWD" not found error. Which on a completely unrelated thread I read had something to do with not installing it with pip.

For other completely unknown reasons, the binaries provided don't seem to want to run. I'm running Python 2.7 and Apache 2.4, both 64-bit on Windows 2012 server.

I had a little trouble at first getting APXS installed and it, at least tells me that:

```
C:\>apxs -q libdir
C:\apache24\lib
```

but I'm not sure if that's the same libdir that python is talking about.

So I hacked `c:\python27\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py` and added:

```
if name == "LIBDIR":
    return "c:\\python27\\lib"
else:
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
```

and that seemed to work, (it didn't some times, but right now it's working:

It had some reservations though:

```
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PCbuild /EXPORT:initmod_wsgi-py27 build\temp
.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_apache.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_buckets.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_convert.obj build\tem
p.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_daemon.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_interp.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_logger.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_memory.obj build\t
emp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_metrics.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_restrict.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_server.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_stream.obj bu
ild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\wsgi_validate.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi-py27.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi-py27.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Releas
e\src/server\mod_wsgi-py27.pyd.manifest -Lc:\python27\lib -Lc:\python27\Lib/config -lpython27
  LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Lc:\python27\lib'; ignored
  LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Lc:\python27\Lib/config'; ignored
  LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/lpython27'; ignored
  LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol initmod_wsgi-py27
  build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi-py27.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
Failed to build mod-wsgi
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi
Successfully installed mod-wsgi-4.4.13
```

and when I tried to run `mod_wsgi-express.exe` I got:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>mod_wsgi-express.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\mod_wsgi-express-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mod-wsgi==4.4.13', 'console_scripts', 'mod_wsgi-express')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pwd
ImportError: No module named pwd
```

which is what I'm at right now, same place I thought installing via pip would fix.

So, I think something is messed up with the libdir part still, or else it should have automatically worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is not supported for the pip installable mod_wsgi at this time. Instead see:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Comment: Hey, thanks for supporting your code so well! I'll stop banging my head against the wall.  I think I got nmake to work after installing 97 Microsoft sdks. Now to configure apache...

Comment: There were also the precompiled binaries, which should be sufficient for most requirements. No need to compile yourself.